# nodeJs soap libarary can not send request to wsdl url

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, wsdl

I Have a SOAP API like `https://example.com/TokenService?wsdl`,
i send a request to create **Client** in below function  :

```
let soap = require('soap');
   soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
       console.log('err is ',err) ;
        client.myFunction(input_params, function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);

        });
    });
```

Then i get an error like this:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '‫‪https:///example.com//TokenService?wsdl‬‬'
>     errno: -2,
>     code: 'ENOENT',
>     syscall: 'open',
>     path: '‫‪https://example.com/TokenService?wsdl‬`

And my **client** is undefiend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're very nearly there. Here's an example of a call you can test:

```
const soap = require('soap');

const url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx';
const wsdlURL = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL';

soap.createClient(wsdlURL, {endpoint: url}, function(error, client) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        client.GetCitiesByCountry({ CountryName: 'Russian Federation'}, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                process.exit(1);
            }
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
```

I think you may just need to pass two urls to the function, the service url and the WSDL url. Sometimes you don't need to do this and the WSDL will contain the links to all the operation URLs. Some calls will work if you omit the {endpoint: url } option, and some won't.

Also check the WSDL link, ensure the WSDL is valid, you can look at it in your browser, it should look like this:

http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

You can also download the WSDL to a file and try that:

```
"use strict";

const wsdlFileName = 'globalweather.wsdl';
const path = require('path');
const wsdlFile = path.join(__dirname, wsdlFileName);

const soap = require('soap');

const url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx';

soap.createClient(wsdlFile, {endpoint: url}, function(error, client) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        client.GetCitiesByCountry({ CountryName: 'Russian Federation'}, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                process.exit(1);
            }
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
```

You need to put the WSDL file in the same directory as your script.

I get can this working in a C# client, the XML POST looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <reservation xmlns="http://token.ws.web.cnpg/">
            <Token_param xmlns="">
                <AMOUNT>amount</AMOUNT>
                <CRN>crn</CRN>
                <MID>mid</MID>
                <REFERALADRESS>referaladdress</REFERALADRESS>
                <SIGNATURE>signature</SIGNATURE>
                <TID>tid</TID>
            </Token_param>
        </reservation>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And the response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:reservationResponse xmlns:ns2="http://token.ws.web.cnpg/">
            <return>
                <result>3</result>
                <token>Security check was not successful.</token>
            </return>
        </ns2:reservationResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I can do a POST to the address by doing the following:

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'https://example.com/TokenService';
var tokenXML = `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <reservation xmlns="http://token.ws.web.cnpg/">
                <Token_param xmlns="">
                    <AMOUNT>amount</AMOUNT>
                    <CRN>crn</CRN>
                    <MID>mid</MID>
                    <REFERALADRESS>referaladdress</REFERALADRESS>
                    <SIGNATURE>signature</SIGNATURE>
                    <TID>tid</TID>
                </Token_param>
            </reservation>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>`;

console.log('Posting..')
console.log(tokenXML);
request.post(
    {url: url,
    body : tokenXML,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
    }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

For some reason the NPM soap library does not like this webservice!
But you could fill in the values in the XML yourself, it might get you a bit further if you have the details you need to fill.

I'm getting the response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:reservationResponse xmlns:ns2="http://token.ws.web.cnpg/">
            <return>
                <result>3</result>
                <token>Security check was not successful.</token>
            </return>
        </ns2:reservationResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

But I don't the the username password maybe. If you can fill in these details maybe you will get a successful response. You need to do an NPM install request BTW to get the request library.

Comment: I tested by to url like `https://example.com` and wsdl url `https://example.com/TokenService?wsdl` but  The same error is displayed.I checked my wsdl url and was valid.

Comment: Ok, that's a strange one, have you tried downloading the WSDL to a file and then using this WSDL to access the service? You can pass in the WSDL file to the createClient function. I'll update the answer with this code, it might be worth a try for you!

Comment: please visit My wsdl url  parameters  image [link](https://pasteboard.co/H5CrxqV.png)

Comment: I can't see any URL, if you sent me this by chat that would be very cool, I'm sure we can figure it out!

Comment: Oh sorry, that might not be possible...if you could link to an image of the url.. I appreciate you wish to keep it private!

Comment: Ok, I can see the object model, but this doesn't contain an Url I can test..as far as I can see. It looks like for some reason the node service cannot reach the WSDL Url. Have you tried setting NODE_DEBUG to net,tls etc to show more errors in the logs? This is worth a try, you might understand more of why this isn't working: http://www.juliengilli.com/2013/05/26/Using-Node.js-NODE_DEBUG-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: Oh great, I can see the WSDL, i'll have a look thanks @Fazel!

Comment: Is there a problem with the nodejs-soap plugin?

Comment: I think it is not creating the correct code to deal with this SOAP service.

Comment: Is there any solution to this problem in nodejs-soap liberary?

Comment: I'm seeing if I can fix it!

Comment: I think it might be easier to use an XML post rather than using the SOAP library, I just get an error creating the client. I've updated my answer to show POSTing the raw XML.

Comment: Thanks. This method solved my problem. There may be a problem with the Soap plugin.

Comment: I've seen this before, the soap library works with some APIs but not all.